# Is it a a bad syntax to use hidden input without label and label surronding inputs whitout for?

Tags: label, wcag2.0

I have two syntax problems with the WCAG 2.0 validator:

- I used hidden input without label (because it's not useful, as those input are hidden and only used to get ID data). So WCAG 2.0 tell me that I have to put label for each input elements.
- I use this syntax :  info input  . But doing this, WCAG 2.0 tells me that there is no text in my labels. But I rode that the two syntax below where ok :

  'label' info input 'input' '/label'
  'label for=""' '/label' 'input/'

So I wonder if I have to ignore the WCAG 2.0 recommendations ?

Comment: Hi Anacarde, what exactly is *the WCAG 2.0 validator*? I know the W3C's HTML validator, but that's a different tool.

Comment: "Web content accessibility guidelines".If the W3C's validator is for the syntax, the WCAG is for the visual accessibility of the website (color, character's size, etc.). Actually, I found a solution to my issue : put "type=hidden" for the input and not surround "input" with "label", but put it above.

Comment: Here is the link : https://achecker.ca/checker/index.php